# Symfony Mailer with SendinBlue configuration problem

Tags: symfony, mailer

I am trying do deploy my website, and i'm using a third party transport to dispatch my emails like : confirmation after subscription and reset password emails.

I am using SendinBlue. I followed Symfony documentation and run `composer require symfony/sendinblue-mailer`

Then i added `MAILER_DSN=sendinblue+smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@default` in my `.env` file. Username and password seems correct, i also encoded special characters in my username.

My website is hosted on OVH, i can connect by SSH and run `php bin/console messenger:consume async`

I have an error message saying : `WARNING   [messenger] Error thrown while handling message Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage. Sending for retry #1 using 1000 ms delay. Error: "Handling "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage" failed: Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp-relay.sendinblue.com:587": stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp-relay.sendinblue.com:587 (Connection refused)"`

I also tried to use the SendinBlue API key and got this message : `WARNING   [messenger] Error thrown while handling message Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage. Sending for retry #1 using 1000 ms delay. Error: "Handling "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage" failed: Could not reach the remote Sendinblue server."`

I guess i missed something, it's the first time i build a symfony application and im a little lost. I spent all day on this and could not find a solution.

Does anyone have an idea what i did wrong ?